# Change all checkbox a true or false with Angular2

Tags: angular

I am trying change all my checkboxs a true or false, with 1 checkbox, in my html I get the change but in console.log(); I get default value

I am using Ngmodel but I think that I have fail with this..

COMPONENT.TS

```
public checkall: boolean = false;
public closures: Array<item>;
```

HTML->

```
<div class="toggle-switch">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" name="checkAll" (change)="check()" [(ngModel)]="checkall">
 <label for="checkAll"></label>
</div>

<tr *ngFor="let closure of closures">

<input type="checkbox" id="{{closure.id}}"  (change) = "check()" name = "{{closure.id}}"[(ngModel)] = "closure.checkclosure"[checked] = "checkall" >
<label for="{{closure.id}}"></label>



check() {
    console.log(this.closures);
}
```

output -> false but in my html my checkbox is true.

Comment: what's in closures?

Comment: yes, sorry, I updated my question . clousures is my Array from server, I use this array with double data binding ("ngModel") for I know that checkbox is true with my console.log

Comment: the problem is that I change in my type="checkbox" id="checkAll" name="checkAll", my html changes a true but in my console.log() not, If I change 1 normally checkbox , I yes get true with console.log();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this works:

**.ts:**

```
  closures = [
    { "id": 1, "checkclosure": false },
    { "id": 2, "checkclosure": false },
    { "id": 3, "checkclosure": false },
    { "id": 4, "checkclosure": false },
    { "id": 5, "checkclosure": false }
  ]

  public checkall: boolean = false;

  check() {
    console.log(this.closures);
  }

  checkAllFunc() {
    this.closures.forEach(elem => {
      elem.checkclosure = this.checkall
    })
  }
```

**.html:**

```
<div class="toggle-switch">
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    id="checkAll"
    name="checkAll"
    (change)="checkAllFunc()"
    [(ngModel)]="checkall">
   <label for="checkAll"></label>
</div>

<hr/>

<div *ngFor="let closure of closures">
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    id="{{closure.id}}"
    (change)="check()"
    name="{{closure.id}}"
    [(ngModel)]="closure.checkclosure">
  <label for="{{closure.id}}"></label>
  {{closure.checkclosure}}
</div>
```

[**Check Demo here**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n7cl3j?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: yes, work, but use forEach, not map (map is for return an array changed)

Comment: @Eliseo I agree. Updated my ans. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it with following code

> TS

```
checkall: boolean = false;
  closures =  [{ "id":1,"checkclosure":false},{ "id":2,"checkclosure":false},{ "id":3,"checkclosure":false},{ "id":4,"checkclosure":false},{ "id":5,"checkclosure":false}]

  check() {
    for(var i in this.closures){ //loop through to update your value of checkbox
      this.closures[i].checkclosure = this.checkall
    }
    console.log(this.closures);
  }
```

> HTML

```
<div class="toggle-switch">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" name="checkAll" (change)="checkAll()" [(ngModel)]="checkall">
 <label for="checkAll"></label>
</div>

<tr *ngFor="let closure of closures">

<input type="checkbox" id="{{closure.id}}"  name = "{{closure.id}}"[(ngModel)] = "closure.checkclosure">
<label for="{{closure.id}}"></label>
```

Comment: the problem is that if my general check is false I do click in 1 checkbox, with your code, my checkbox always is false because my general check is false.

Comment: for eg : call this in ts  singleCheck(){
    console.log(this.closures);

  }

Comment: and HTML <tr *ngFor="let closure of closures">

<input type="checkbox" id="{{closure.id}}"  name = "{{closure.id}}"[(ngModel)] = "closure.checkclosure"[checked] = "checkall" (change)="check()">

Comment: for (... in ...) statements must be filtered with an if statement (forin)

Comment: nop, I get error in visualCode  for(var i in this.closures){

Comment: its working fine at my end, try changing public closures: Array<item>; to  closures = []

Answer (score 0):

Your `checkall` value is flowing only from component to template and is not bound to the value of `closure.checkclosure` just because they happen to be on the same element. I.E. `closure.checkclosure` won't get updated unless you update it by clicking on the element / programatically.

I'd go with:

```
check(event) {
  this.closures = this.closures.map(closure => {
    return {...closure, checkclosure: this.checkall};
  });
}
```

and I would change the template like so:

```
<div *ngFor="let closure of closures">
  <input type="checkbox" id="{{closure.id}}" name="{{closure.id}}" [(ngModel)]="closure.checkclosure">
  <label for="{{closure.id}}"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Im sorry, I fixed the code. Give it a try now, please.

Comment: klemen ..... now my General checkbox actually others checkboxs but If I want only actually 1 checkbox is impossible.